# A Vector Problem

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

$A，B$ and $C$ are three distinct points in 3D space. Let $a，b$ and $c$ be their respective position vectors.

My question is how to prove that the equation of the plane through $A, B$ and $C$ can be written as

$$(xi+yi+zk)·(a \times b+b\times c+c \times a)=a·(b \times c)$$

Comment: Sorry,I‘ve corrected it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reminder: the equation of a plane can be written

$$ax+by+cz=d \ \iff \ (a,b,c)\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}=d$$

where the vector with coordiantes $(a,b,c)$ is a vector normal to the plane.

---

Consider the following normal vector to the plane:

$$N=\vec{AB} \times \vec{AC}=(\vec{OB} -\vec{OA}) \times (\vec{OC}-\vec{OA})$$

$$N=\vec{OB} \times \vec{OC} - \vec{OB} \times \vec{OA} - \vec{OA} \times \vec{OC} + \underbrace{\vec{OA} \times \vec{OA}}_0$$

$$N=\vec{OB} \times \vec{OC} + \vec{OA} \times \vec{OB} + \vec{OC} \times \vec{OA}$$

as desired for the LHS.

Therefore, the plane equation is

$$N.\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}=k\tag{1}$$

for a certain constant $k$.

As $A$ is a point of the plane, by definition of an equation, (1) will be fulfilled if we takewe can  $\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}=\vec{OA}$

(1) will become:

$$k=N.\vec{OA}=(\vec{OB} \times \vec{OC} + \vec{OA} \times \vec{OB} + \vec{OC} \times \vec{OA}).\vec{OA}$$

$$k=N.\vec{OA}=(\vec{OB} \times \vec{OC}).\vec{OA} + \underbrace{(\vec{OA} \times \vec{OB}).\vec{OA}}_0 + \underbrace{(\vec{OC} \times \vec{OA}).\vec{OA}}_0$$

giving indeed the "mixed product" we were awaiting